# Confused by javascript's constructor and prototype?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype-programming

```
function MyObject(){}
Array.prototype={};
MyObject.prototype={};
var a=new Array();
var b=new MyObject();
alert(a.constructor==Array);//true
alert(b.constructor==MyObject);//false
```

Comment: There is a nice article about it here: http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html

Comment: thank you,i am reading it right now.

Comment: Indeed, this stuff is very confusing!  See my article on the subject; perhaps it will unconfuse you. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/06/53352.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Array.prototype` is a non-writable property.

As such, your assignment:

```
Array.prototype = {}
```

...doesn't succeed, and so its `.constructor` property hasn't changed.

[15.4.3.1 Array.prototype](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.3.1)

> The initial value of `Array.prototype` is the Array prototype object (15.4.4).
>
> This property has the attributes `{ [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }`

...whereas with your custom constructor, you have the ability to assign a different prototype object, so you've overwritten the original which had reference to the constructor via `.constructor`.

Answer (score 2):

The `constructor` property is overwritten when you override the `prototype` property with your own empty object instance, since `({}).constructor === Object`. You can do either

```
function MyObject() {}
MyObject.prototype = {};
MyObject.prototype.constructor = MyObject;
```

or (better IMO) you can not set `prototype` directly, but instead augment it:

```
function MyObject() {}
MyObject.prototype.foo = "bar";
```

Also of note: `Array.prototype` is not writable, so your line `Array.prototype = {}` will silently fail (or noisily fail in strict mode).

Answer (score 0):

```
> function MyObject(){} 
> Array.prototype={};
```

You can't assign a value to Array.prototype.

```
> MyObject.prototype={};
> var a=new Array();
> var b=new MyObject();
> alert(a.constructor==Array);//true
```

*Array.prototype* has a *constructor* property that references the *Array* function. Since a is an instance of *Array*, it inherits *Array.prototype*'s constructor property.

```
> alert(b.constructor==MyObject);//false
```

You have assigned an empty object to *MyObject.prototype*, it does not have a *prototype* property, nor does *b*.

```
MyObject.prototype.constructor = MyObject;

alert(b.constructor==MyObject); // true
```